# Why is git diff output different for 2 hashes vs 1?

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to figure out why is output for git diff [branch_name] [hash] different from git diff [hash] while standing on [branch_name]? (Note SHARED folder for diff with [hash] and DWH4DMS folder for diff with [branch_name] and [hash])
Example as follows:

```
U_M14V5@A120621 MINGW64 /d/tst/packer/local_repo (DWH4DM-9676)
$ git status
On branch DWH4DM-9676
nothing to commit, working tree clean

U_M14V5@A120621 MINGW64 /d/tst/packer/local_repo (DWH4DM-9676)
$ git diff --name-only fb6066b88ecd4
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/DWH4DMS/mappings/m_IFRSBALANCE_SSTAT__CBBALANCE_DMDELTA.xml
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/DWH4DMS/mapplets/mpl_CBTERDEP_UK_rg.xml
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/DWH4DMS/sessions/s_m_IFRSBALANCE_SSTAT__CBBALANCE_DMDELTA.xml
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/SHARED/mapplets/mpl_CBTERDEP_UK.xml

U_M14V5@A120621 MINGW64 /d/tst/packer/local_repo (DWH4DM-9676)
$ git diff --name-only DWH4DM-9676 fb6066b88ecd4
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/DWH4DMS/mappings/m_IFRSBALANCE_SSTAT__CBBALANCE_DMDELTA.xml
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/DWH4DMS/mapplets/mpl_CBTERDEP_UK.xml
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/DWH4DMS/mapplets/mpl_CBTERDEP_UK_rg.xml
ETL/Informatica/REP_DW_PROD/DWH4DMS/sessions/s_m_IFRSBALANCE_SSTAT__CBBALANCE_DMDELTA.xml
```

Comment: What is the output if using `--name-status`? _and_ also show the output using `fb6066b88ecd4 DWH4DM-9676`. And also, I assume that nothing is going on between the moment when you started running the first command and the last one, right?

Comment: Nice, you're right. It seems that DWH4DM-9676 fb6066b88ecd4 diff shows DWH4DMS file because it was deleted and if i run fb6066b88ecd4 DWH4DM-9676 it shows the correct SHARED file (which was moved aka added). Everything is clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you use a single revision, you are not comparing with `HEAD`, you compare with what you have on the working tree.

Second theory:
There was a renamed file so it is displaying the file path for 2 different revisions.

Comment: Doesn't "working tree clean, on branch DWH4DM-9676" mean that HEAD (tip of DWH4DM-9676 since i'm standing on DWH4DM-9676) and working tree have same contents?

Comment: Hmm. interesting. Was there a renamed file?

Comment: Hmm.... the renamed file might actually explain it. It would be displaying the name of the file in different revisions (DWH4DM-9676 vs fb6066b88ec4)

Comment: So, if you try `git diff --name-only fb6066b88ecd4 DWH4DM-9676`, you should get the same output of `git diff --name-only fb6066b88ecd4`